# Which font weights does Bootstrap 4 use by default?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to import a new font from Google Fonts and want to ensure that I grab the appropriate font weights. What are the defaults used? I did a quick look around and it seems like 300 and 500 are used, but any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the latest Bootstrap 4.1.3 _variables.scss (from which the bootstrap.css is built)...

```
$font-weight-light: 300;
$font-weight-normal: 400;
$font-weight-bold: 700; 
..
$headings-font-weight: 500;
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. This doesn't seem documented, or at least not easily discoverable using Bootstrap's fancy Algolia search thing.

Comment: I wish they documented it here, for example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults

Comment: @Abram You can always find it from the source in GitHub: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss

Comment: It seems that using `<b>` or `<strong>` on a header gives you `font-weight: bolder` which renders font weight of 900... just noticed.